# Can't get command in slack slash command request

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I created a slash command on slack.

However when I trigger it the post request I receive on my server is as following :

```
{'version': '2.0',
 'routeKey': 'POST /server',
 'rawPath': '/Work/server',
 'rawQueryString': '',
 'headers': {'accept': 'application/json,*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  'content-length': '421',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'host': 'xxx',
  'user-agent': 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)',
  'x-amzn-trace-id': 'xxx',
  'x-forwarded-for': 'xxx',
  'x-forwarded-port': '443',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'x-slack-request-timestamp': '1616684124',
  'x-slack-signature': 'xxx'},
 'requestContext': {'accountId': '255912899710',
  'apiId': 'xxx',
  'domainName': 'xxx',
  'domainPrefix': 'xxx',
  'http': {'method': 'POST',
   'path': '/Work/Slack_interaction',
   'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1',
   'sourceIp': '3.89.205.168',
   'userAgent': 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)'},
  'requestId': 'cv6edg75iGYEJaQ=',
  'routeKey': 'POST /Slack_interaction',
  'stage': 'Work',
  'time': '25/Mar/2021:14:55:24 +0000',
  'timeEpoch': 1616684124418},
 'body': 'xxxtokenxxx',
 'isBase64Encoded': True}
```

I don't get any `command` or `text` key as it should be according to the [doc](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#app_command_handling).

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the details of the interaction are within the body of the payload, a body that is currently encoded as suggested by the field 'isBase64Encoded': True

You should be able to get all the information you need once you decode it. My implementation uses python's [base64 library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) but I'm sure you can find an equivalent tool for whichever language you are using.

Libraries like [slack bolt](https://api.slack.com/tools/bolt) also take care of this step for you, amongst many others.

Note that from my testing **all interaction payloads are encoded as such**, event payloads on the other hand are not and can be parsed directly